# How do I connect a microcontroller to the cellular internet network wirelessly?

Tags: arduino, antenna, communication, wireless, embedded

I am working on a project where I have to wirelessly turn on and off Electric motor pump, which is at a distance of approximately 500 meter from my home. I need help to select the wireless communication so that I can send data from my home either to turn off or on the motor.
Also is it possible to connect my micro-controller to the internet of cellular network wirelessly(Without a GSM module)

Comment: What is available at these locations? Wifi, 3G etc?

Comment: You could use a RockBlock Iridium satellite module, but that's hugely overkill.

Comment: Wait, are you asking for a suitable point to point connection? In that case,  you might be able to use a HC-12, but that largely depends on any obstructions in the way.

Comment: @jramsay42 There is now wifi ,but 2G and 4G is available

Comment: @skillz21 yes the location has lot more coconut tree

Comment: Ok, theoretically, it should work. In open air, two HC-12 modules can talk to each other at a distance of 1.5+km